# React Native: Best way to store access token. AsyncStorage or Redux Store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, local-storage, asyncstorage

I am developing React Native app. I need to use access token for auth requests. Currently I am storing it in redux store. But on refresh token become null. So I was thinking of using AsyncStorage to store token. But don't know which one is fast. I can use Persist with redux store to keep token for long time as well.
One more issue with AsyncStorage is that I can't get token without using await, and for that I must use this inside async function. But I will require it in other places as well where I can't use async function , like to in header configs of post request where I set Authorization for all request.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: AsyncStorage is good in my opinion. Your async function won't be a big problem as you want to retrieve the token from the storage only on app start and then safe it in an AuthContext where you can always retrieve it.

Comment: Use Redux-persist

Answer (score 0):

Both comments are correct - if you want to reuse the access token when the user enters the app again after a short time, it becomes really handy to have the token still in the async storage.

For usage within the app it is then better to have the token in redux or the AuthContext, if you use that one.

Now Redux-persist is a combination of both, gets you the methods to automatically load data into store on starting the app and also put them back into storage.